# How to force-download all Firefox files

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code to download `octet` files in Firefox:

```
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream")  
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/force-download")
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

However, I would like to download **all** / any files from Firefox, not just unknown octet-stream files. How would this be done?

Comment: From what I recall, it is not possible to do with Firefox. You have to specify the mime type(s) explicitly.

Comment: You need to specify all mime types. Its painful, I know.